# glVertexAttribPointer gives NameError: name 'ArrayDatatype' is not defined?

Tags: python, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, pyopengl

I'm using PyOpenGL Library with GLES2 and EGL to run a program on a NanoPi M1 Plus with a Mali400 GPU. glVertexAttribPointer function gives me an error saying: NameError: name 'ArrayDatatype' is not defined. However, if I use OpenGL.GL.glVertexAttribPointer it does not give me any error, however, the rest of the code is all written using GLES2. I am not sure if I can make this single call using OpenGL.GL or are the arguments that I am passing wrong?

Line of Code casuing problem:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(ctypes.c_float), ctypes.c_void_p(0*sizeof(ctypes.c_float)) )
```

Buffering data code:

```
vbo = glGenBuffers(1)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(ctypes.c_float) * len(vertices), (ctypes.c_float * len(vertices))(*vertices), GL_STATIC_DRAW)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ferb_gpu_1.py", line 219, in <module>
    vec_add_gpu(A, B, C, 1000)
  File "ferb_gpu_1.py", line 206, in vec_add_gpu
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(ctypes.c_float), ctypes.c_void_p(0*sizeof(ctypes.c_float)) )
  File "/home/fa/berryconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenGL/latebind.py", line 61, in __call__
    return self.wrapperFunction( self.baseFunction, *args, **named )
  File "/home/fa/berryconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenGL/GLES2/VERSION/GLES2_2_0.py", line 400, in glVertexAttribPointer
    array = ArrayDatatype.asArray( pointer, type )
NameError: name 'ArrayDatatype' is not defined
```

Complete Code if needed:

```
import numpy as np
import ctypes
import os
os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':0.0'
if not os.environ.get( 'PYOPENGL_PLATFORM' ):
    os.environ['PYOPENGL_PLATFORM'] = 'egl'
import OpenGL
from OpenGL.GL import ArrayDatatype
from OpenGL.EGL import *
from OpenGL.GLES2 import *
from OpenGL import arrays
if os.environ.get( 'TEST_NO_ACCELERATE' ):
    OpenGL.USE_ACCELERATE = False

def LoadShader(stype, shaderSrc):
    shader = glCreateShader(stype)
    if(shader == 0):
        print("Error returned 0")
        if(glGetError()!=GL_NO_ERROR):
            print('GLerror')
        return 0
    glShaderSource(shader, shaderSrc)
    glCompileShader(shader)
    if glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) != GL_TRUE:
        raise RuntimeError(glGetShaderInfoLog(shader))
    return shader

display, context, surface = None, None, None

configAttribs =[
    EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_PBUFFER_BIT,
    EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
    EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
    EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
    EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 8,
    EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
    EGL_NONE
]

pbufferAttribs=[
    EGL_WIDTH, 
    1000,
    EGL_HEIGHT, 
    2,
    EGL_NONE
]

contextAttribs=[
    EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2,
    EGL_NONE
]

vertexShaderCode = '''
    attribute vec4 vPosition;
    void main() {
        gl_Position = vPosition;
    }
'''

fragmentShaderCode = {}

fragmentShaderCode[0] = '''
    precision highp float;
    uniform float Aarr[1000];
    uniform float Barr[1000];

    vec4 EncodeRangeV4(float value, float minVal, float maxVal) {
        value        = clamp( (value-minVal) / (maxVal-minVal), 0.0, 1.0 );
        value       *= 0.99999994039;
        vec4 encode  = fract( value * vec4(1.0, 256.0, 65536.0, 16777216.0) );
        return vec4( encode.xyz - encode.yzw / 256.0, encode.w );
    }

    void main() {

        int my_index = int(gl_FragCoord[0]);
        float result = Aarr[my_index] + Barr[my_index];

        gl_FragColor = EncodeRangeV4(result, -512.0, 512.0) - (1.0/1300.0);
    }
'''

vertices=(
    -1, -1, 1,
    -1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1,
    -1, -1, 1,
    1, 1, 1,
    1, -1, 1)

prog_array = {}

display = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY)
if(display == EGL_NO_DISPLAY):
    print("Failed to get EGL display! Error: %s", eglGetError())
    exit()

print("Egl error after display ",eglGetError())

major,minor = ctypes.c_long(), ctypes.c_long()
if not eglInitialize( display, major, minor):
    print("Unable to initialize")
    exit()

print("Egl error after initalize ",eglGetError())

configAttribs = arrays.GLintArray.asArray(configAttribs)
num_configs = ctypes.c_long()
config = (EGLConfig*1)()
eglChooseConfig(display, configAttribs, config, 1, num_configs)
print("Egl error after config ",eglGetError())

eglBindAPI(EGL_OPENGL_ES_API)

pbufferAttribs_list = pbufferAttribs[:]
pbufferAttribs_list = arrays.GLintArray.asArray(pbufferAttribs_list)
surface = eglCreatePbufferSurface(display, config[0], pbufferAttribs_list)

print("Egl error after surface ",eglGetError())

contextAttribs = arrays.GLintArray.asArray(contextAttribs)
context = eglCreateContext(display, config[0], EGL_NO_CONTEXT, contextAttribs)
print("Egl error after context ",eglGetError())

eglMakeCurrent(display, surface, surface, context)

print("Egl error after make current ",eglGetError())

desiredWidth, desiredHeight = pbufferAttribs[1], pbufferAttribs[3]
glViewport(0, 0, desiredWidth, desiredHeight)
#viewport = glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT)

print("Egl get error",eglGetError())
if(glGetError()!=GL_NO_ERROR):
    print('GLerror')

glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
if(glGetError()!=GL_NO_ERROR):
    print('GLerror')

prog_array[0] = glCreateProgram()
if(glGetError()!=GL_NO_ERROR):
    print('GLerror')

vert = LoadShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode)
frag = LoadShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode[0])
glAttachShader(prog_array[0], vert)
glAttachShader(prog_array[0], frag)
glLinkProgram(prog_array[0])

glUseProgram(prog_array[0])

vec_A = glGetUniformLocation(prog_array[0], 'Aarr')
vec_B = glGetUniformLocation(prog_array[0], 'Barr')
print("vec a ",vec_A, "type: ", type(vec_A))
print("vec b ",vec_B, "type: ", type(vec_B))

vbo = glGenBuffers(1)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(ctypes.c_float) * len(vertices), (ctypes.c_float * len(vertices))(*vertices), GL_STATIC_DRAW)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo) 
glUseProgram(prog_array[0])
width, height = pbufferAttribs[1], pbufferAttribs[3]

vec_A = glGetUniformLocation(prog_array[0], 'Aarr')
vec_B = glGetUniformLocation(prog_array[0], 'Barr')
print("vec a ",vec_A, "type: ", type(vec_A))
print("vec b ",vec_B, "type: ", type(vec_B))
glUniform1fv(vec_A, n, A)
glUniform1fv(vec_B, n, B)


glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(ctypes.c_float), ctypes.c_void_p(0*sizeof(ctypes.c_float)) )
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 18)
eglSwapBuffers(display, surface)

buffer = glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)
print("Buffer: ", buffer[0:10], "Len: ",len(buffer))
parse_output_buffer_vec_add(buffer, n, C)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After viewing the code on GitHub and the error I was receiving, I realized that the code on GitHub had already fixed the problem. I did a conda update for the package and still received this error. However, the same code when using pyopengl installed using pip did not give this error.